# get country from Nominatim GeoPy response

Tags: python, openstreetmap, geocoding, geopy

When using NOminatim with GeoPy to encode given address strings, how does one get the country information?

Is there any structured way to get the country name in the output? One way is to take the string after the last "," to get the country, but doesnt seem like a robust way to do so.

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent='myapplication')
x = 'PA - Cranberry Township'
location = geolocator.geocode(x, exactly_one=True,language="english", namedetails=True)
# how to get country name from response
location.raw


{'place_id': 259010359,
 'licence': 'Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. https://osm.org/copyright',
 'osm_type': 'relation',
 'osm_id': 4131949,
 'boundingbox': ['40.673669', '40.7453357', '-80.1525583', '-80.0559393'],
 'lat': '40.7099343',
 'lon': '-80.1060506',
 'display_name': 'Cranberry Township, Butler County, Pennsylvania, 16066, United States',
 'class': 'boundary',
 'type': 'administrative',
 'importance': 0.6463910141518243,
 'icon': 'https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/ui/mapicons//poi_boundary_administrative.p.20.png',
 'namedetails': {'name': 'Cranberry Township',
  'name:en': 'Cranberry Township',
  'official_name': 'Cranberry Township'}}
```

Comment: why is split the display_name by comma and taking whatever you need from it not robust?

Comment: im unsure if that last string is always the country

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here you go:**

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent='myapplication')
x = 'PA - Cranberry Township'
location = geolocator.geocode(x, exactly_one=True, language="en", namedetails=True, addressdetails=True)
print(location.raw)
print(f"""Country Name: {location.raw['address']['country']}""")
```

**Output:**

```
{
   "place_id":258908396,
   "licence":"Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. https://osm.org/copyright",
   "osm_type":"relation",
   "osm_id":4131949,
   "boundingbox":[
      "40.673669",
      "40.7453357",
      "-80.1525583",
      "-80.0559393"
   ],
   "lat":"40.7099343",
   "lon":"-80.1060506",
   "display_name":"Cranberry Township, Butler County, Pennsylvania, 16066, United States",
   "class":"boundary",
   "type":"administrative",
   "importance":0.6463910141518243,
   "icon":"https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/ui/mapicons//poi_boundary_administrative.p.20.png",
   "address":{
      "town":"Cranberry Township",
      "county":"Butler County",
      "state":"Pennsylvania",
      "postcode":"16066",
      "country":"United States",
      "country_code":"us"
   },
   "namedetails":{
      "name":"Cranberry Township",
      "name:en":"Cranberry Township",
      "official_name":"Cranberry Township"
   }
}
Country Name: United States
```